# How to redirect to another page after click on submit button in form with required inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to redirect to index.html after clicking on button in a form. I tried this:

```
$("#btn").on("click", function() { 
  window.location.replace("index.html");
  localeStorage.clear();
})
```

However in the form I have required inputs, so when I had some empty required input, it redirected, but at the same time it said that I must write something to input.

I need to redirect to index.html after successful form submission. Like on a eshop after submitting an order

Comment: You need to do the redirection on the page that this form submits to. Not this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you want the form to be validated first before the redirection you need to place the event on the `submit` of the form, not the `click` of the button.

Secondly, performing a redirect in JS when the form is submit is redundant; just set the `action` of the form to where you want the user to be sent.

With the above in mind, try this:

```html
<form id="yourForm" action="index.html">
  <input type="text" name="foo" required />
  <!-- Some more 'required' form controls... -->

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
$("#yourForm").on("submit", function() { 
  localeStorage.clear();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is to verify that the inputs are present before the redirect:

```
$("#btn").on("click", function() { 
   // do some checks

   //if checks ok call redirect, if ko returns
   window.location.replace("index.html");
   localeStorage.clear();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the values, use fetch to send the form and then redirect.

( You can add some gestion of server response before redirect. Like "Login already in database ... )

```
$("#btn").on("click", function() { 
  const verif = *verifAndFormat(...)* // function that return json like {valid:true , data:... }
  if( verif.valid ){
    fetch( URL , {method:'POST', body: verif.data} )
    .then( resp =>{
      /*some operations*/
      localeStorage.clear();
      window.location.replace("index.html");
    })
    .catch( err => /*error gestion*/
  }else{
    /*Invalid value gestion*/
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $(function(){  
    $('#btn').On('click', function() {
window.location.href="../index.html";
}
}
```

And also you can call it form html coding on click event to call function submit and redirect from that..
html coding

```
<input type="button" id="btn" onclick="submit()"/>
```

Javascript coding

```
function submit(){
window.location.replace("http://webpagename.index.html");
}
```